# A counterexample of Riemann mapping theorem in high dimension

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

There is an exercise (1.1.16) in Huybrechts: the polidisc $B_{(1,1)}(0)\subset\mathbb C^2$ and the unit disc $D$ in $\mathbb C^2$ can not be biholomorphic.

The hint is to compare the automorphisms of these two sets. The unitary matrices is a subgroup of the group of biholomorphic maps of $D$ which leaves the origin fixed. Clearly, the group of unitary matrices of $\dim 2$ is not abelian and the group of biholomorphic maps of $B_{(1,1)}(0)$ is transitive. If we can show the group of biholomorphic maps of $B_{(1,1)}(0)$ which leave invariant the origin is abelian, then this will complete the proof.

If we set $f_1(z_1,z_2)=(z_2,z_1)$ and $f_2(z_1,z_2)=(e^{i\pi/3}z_1,e^{i2\pi/3}z_2)$, then these are clearly in biholomorphic maps of $B_{(1,1)}(0)$. However, $f_1\circ f_2\neq f_2\circ f_1$.

Please tell me where is the problem. Any hint is helpful. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Your observations are correct, there is an error in Huybrechts' book. A slightly simpler counterexample is $f_1(z_1, z_2) = (z_2, z_1)$ and $f_2(z_1, z_2) = (-z_1, z_2)$. Maybe he means that the group of biholomorphisms of the form $(f_1(z_1), f_2(z_2))$ is abelian, but then I don't see how that helps with the proof.

Comment: the group of biholomorphims of $U$ and of $V$ are isomorphic if you have a biholomorphism  $U \to V$

Comment: I am aware of that, but how is that relevant here? The exercise in Huybrechts asks the reader to show the group of biholomorphisms of the polydisc leaving the origin invariant is an abelian group. As the OP demonstrates, it is not an abelian group. I am merely confirming that the OP is correct, and Huybrechts is mistaken.

Comment: I thought you said "if it was abelian it wouldn't help anyway". And there is a good chance to use the $U \simeq V$ property for showing there is no biholomorphism $D \to B_{1,1}$

Comment: If the group of all biholomorphisms leaving the origin invariant was abelian, then there would be a contradiction, but if the subgroup I mentioned was abelian, there would be no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just guessing that the identity component of the group is abelian.